# ¿Cómo rotar una matriz en Java?

Tags: java

```
public void rotarCuadrado90Grados( ){
    int tam=0, k=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrizMagica.length; i++) {
        k=matrizMagica[0].length;
    for (int j = 0; j < matrizMagica[0].length; j++) {

        Numero [][] a=new Numero[tam][tam];

        a[k][i]=matrizMagica[i][j];
        k--;
```

Comment: Con un poco del codigo que has intentado, podríamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Hola @FelipeCortés, no coloques código en los comentarios, porque es muy complicado entenderlo. Edita tu pregunta para mostrar tu código. El editor  cuenta con ayuda, por si la necesitas.

Comment: Gracias amigo.!

Comment: Hola Felipe, ¿cual es el problema con el código? Por favor lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y luego mejora tu pregunta para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: Pero que pretendes hacer? Quieres invertir la matriz?

Comment: Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de como aparecería una matriz original y como debería quedar.

Answer (score 2):

Primero que todo asumo que tienes una [matríz cuadrada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_cuadrada), puesto que inicializas una matríz de tamaño *m*, y asumo que cuando dices rotar 90 grados es hacer lo siguiente:

```
1, 2, 3       9, 8, 7
4, 5, 6  = >  6, 5, 4
7, 8, 9       3, 2, 1
```

A lo cual puedes resolverlo mediante el siguiente código

```
public int[][] rotarCuadrado90Grados(int [][] matOriginal)
{
  int fil = matOriginal.length;
  int col = matOriginal[0].length;
  int contFil = 0;
  int contCol = 0;
  int[][] matNueva = new int [fil][col]
  for (int i = fil; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    contCol =  0;
    for (int j = col; j >= 0; j--)
    {
      matNueva[contFil][contCol] = matOriginal[i][j];
      contCol ++;
    }
    contFil ++;
  }
  return matNueva;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Programa para rotar cuadrado en 90 grados.
>   [1, 2, 3]      => |   [9, 8, 7]
>     [4, 5, 6]     => |   [6, 5, 4]
>     [7, 8, 9]    =>  |   [3, 2, 1]

int matriz[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, //Declaramos la matriz que deseamos rotar
            {4, 5, 6},
            {7, 8, 9}};

```
        for (int i = matriz.length-1; i >=0 ; i--) { //Posición de columna
            for (int j = matriz.length-1; j >=0; j--) { //Posición de fila
                System.err.print(matriz[i][j]); //Intercambiamos valores de la primera fila y la primera columna. Con esto realizamos el movimiento de 90
            }
            System.err.println(""); // Salto de línea
        }
```

> Resultado: [9][8][7]
>   [6][5][4]
>   [3][2][1]

Comment: Deberías explicar que hace el código y como ayuda esto a la respuesta de la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Rotación a 90° de una matriz:

```
a,b,c,d           m,i,e,a
e,f,g,h     ->    n,j,f,b
i,j,k,l     ->    ñ,k,g,c
m,n,ñ,o           o,l,h,d
```

Podemos implementar una operación que reciba la matriz a rotar y retorne la nueva ya ordenada:

```
public String[][] rotateMatrix(String[][] matrix)
{
    int tamanho = matrix.length;
    String[][] novaMatrix = new String[tamanho][tamanho];

    for(int i = 0, j = tamanho - 1; i < tamanho && j >= 0; i++, j--)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < tamanho; k++)
        {
            novaMatrix[k][j] = matrix[i][k];
        }               
    }       
    return novaMatrix; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rotar 90º

```
public static int[][] rotarMatriz90(int[][] matriz) {

    int tamanio = matriz.length;
    int[][] nuevamatriz = new int[tamanio][tamanio];

    for (int x=0;x<tamanio;x++) {
        for (int y=0;y<tamanio;y++) {
            nuevamatriz[y][tamanio-1-x] = matriz[x][y];
        }
    }

    return nuevamatriz;
}
```

Hay una explicación del ejemplo en http://lineadecodigo.com/java/rotar-una-matriz/

Rotar 90º En sentido Antihorario

```
public static int[][] rotarMatriz90Antihorario(int[][] matriz) {

    int tamanio = matriz.length;
    int[][] nuevamatriz = new int[tamanio][tamanio];

    for (int x=0;x<tamanio;x++) {
        for (int y=0;y<tamanio;y++) {
            nuevamatriz[tamanio-1-y][x] = matriz[x][y];
        }
    }

    return nuevamatriz;
}
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [answer]. En lo posible, evita responder a preguntas de baja calidad, y si respondes a una pregunta con código, explica mínimamente el funcionamiento del mismo. Lectura recomendada: acerca de [explicar el código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)